# Passing div to jquery function and get its innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a function to print the content of a div. Let me share my aspx markup.

```
<div>
<div id="printarea" runat="server">
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print Div" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" />
```

In the OnClick event innerhtml is set to the div printarea. The code is:

```
 protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string divText = GenerateInPatientBill();// "content you want to print";
        printarea.InnerHtml = divText;

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "script", "PrintDiv(" + printarea.ClientID + ");", true);
    }
```

I need to pass the clientid of printarea div to the javascript function and get it printed. The javascript function used is

```
 function PrintDiv(printarea1) {
    alert($("#" + printarea1 + ""));
    var printContent = $("#" + printarea1 + "").html();
    alert(printContent);
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=400,location=no,left=200px');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(printContent);
    popupWin.document.close();
    popupWin.focus();
    popupWin.print();
    popupWin.close();
}
```

Am getting javascript syntax error at line 2. Please help me on this.

Comment: can please post the error here ?

Comment: Before you get mad, use `console.log()` over `alert()`.

Comment: Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object ]
And am getting the error at the alert() itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below.

```
function printDiv(DivIdToPrint) 
{ 
  var divToPrint= document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint'); 
  var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window','width=100,height=100'); 
  newWin.document.open(); 
  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>'); 
  newWin.document.close(); 
  setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10); 
}
```

This JavaScript will open a new window with the content of the div, will print it and then will close that window. Last line, this is a must to set a timeout there, Otherwise in IE window will get closed before printing happens.

Else you can use a [jQuery plugin](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)

Comment: I got it printed but without any style and formatting. How can we have a formatted printing?

Answer (score 0):

printContent wouldn't be available in newly opened window like so you are getting this error.To overcome this you should simple pass the div contents or markup to the newly opened window and then print